# Sharing violation during save as on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c#, linux, io, save

I'm new to C# and I'm having a bit of an issue when saving to a new file. My program has two options for saving: save & save as.

I was getting a sharing violation error when saving, but I fixed that by closing the previous filestream. However, I still cant figure out why my save as code is giving me a sharing violation error.

Here's the code:

```
        // get a file stream from the file chooser
        FileStream file = File.OpenWrite(saveFc.Filename);
        // check to see if the file is Ok
        bool fileOk = file.CanWrite;
        if (fileOk == true)
        {
            // get the filename
            string filename = file.Name;
            // store the filename for later use
            UtilityClass.filename = filename;
            // get the text from textview1
            string text = textview1.Buffer.Text;
            // get a StreamWriter
            StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filename);
            // write to the file
            writer.Write(text);
            // close/save the file
            writer.Close();
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    // close the file c
```

If you could help me figure it out that would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the code... I am posting this from a tablet and having trouble formatting. I'll fix it when I can. Or as much as I hate to ask if someone else could fix it, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're opening the same file twice:

```
FileStream file = File.OpenWrite(saveFc.Filename);
```

And:

```
string filename = file.Name;
StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filename);
```

Your code could probably be simplified to:

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText(saveFc.Filename))
{
    // store the filename for later use
    UtilityClass.filename = saveFc.Filename;

    // get the text from textview1
    string text = textview1.Buffer.Text;

    // write the text
    writer.Write(text);
}
```

If you open the file with CreateText/OpenWrite it will always be writeable (or an exception will be thrown). The `using` block will automatically close the `writer` when it exits.